# Import VTK in Python Interpreter

Tags: python, vtk

**Goal**: Trying to use VTK library in Python Interpreter.

**What I did**: I have installed VTK using CMake with option VTK_WRAP_PYTHON and Shared_Library enabled and build the VTK in visual studio and it has finished with all builds successfully. 
Then I made the Python_Path.

**Problem**: When I try to import vtk library into python, I get the following error message:

```
>>> import vtk

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import vtk
  File "...\VTK\VTKvisual\Wrapping\Python\vtk\__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from vtkFilteringPython import *
ImportError: No module named vtkFilteringPython
```

Any thoughts that why this is happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you've added the location of the VTK package directory, containing .py files such as "filtering.py" and "vtkFilteringPython.pyd", to your PYTHONPATH.

However, now you need to add **both** this directory and **also** the directory containing vtkFilteringPythonD.dll and the other DLLs to your PATH. The location of this directory depends on whether you've just run the build, or also the INSTALL target. Usually it's in "VTK\bin" or "VTK\bin\BUILDTARGET" somewhere, where BUILDTARGET is for example Debug or Release.

Answer (score 0):

Try running sudo apt-get install python-vtk

Answer (score 0):

If you're only using the Python wrappers, right now, you can just install it from PyPI. Just do `pip install vtk` and you'll get the current version (which is now 8.1).

Look [here](http://prabhuramachandran.blogspot.in/2018/01/vtk-810-wheels-for-all-platforms-on-pypi.html) for the announcement.